# Not able to register Security Policy for Camel Route

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to add spring security role bead authorization policy to spring boot based apache camel web app to secure the routes.

I am using the example(http://camel.apache.org/spring-security-example.html) as a base which is not a spring boot based one.

Since, I am using a Spring Boot based apache camel application am stuck on how to proceed.

I want to know how I can add beans/components through code for registering the authorization policy to be referred in one or more camel routes.

With Spring Boot added I am not sure how we can retain certain components in Camel xml configuration and add other required
beans components in Java config/spring boot.

So, I am not able to convert this non-spring boot example to a apache camel spring boot based application.

Can someone help me on the right way to approach the problem.

I have defined  as below in java config.

```
@Bean(name="roleUserEmp")
      public SpringSecurityAccessPolicy roleUserEmp() {
            SpringSecurityAccessPolicy policy = new SpringSecurityAccessPolicy("ROLE_USER_EMP");
            return policy;
       }
```

Also, I have the stacktrace as below

```
org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route createEmpFlow at: >>> Policy[ref:roleUserEmp] <<< in route: Route(createEmpFlow)[[From[direct:createEmpFlow]] -> [... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: roleUserEmp of type: org.apache.camel.spi.Policy
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:94) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:38) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:854) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.company.application.EmpApplication.main(EmpApplication.java:48) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route createEmpFlow at: >>> Policy[ref:roleUserEmp] <<< in route: Route(createEmpFlow)[[From[direct:createEmpFlow]] -> [... because of No bean could be found in the registry for: roleUserEmp of type: org.apache.camel.spi.Policy
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1072) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:947) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3258) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2981) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2812) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2808) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2831) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2808) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2777) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:92) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: roleUserEmp of type: org.apache.camel.spi.Policy
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:159) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.TransactedDefinition.doResolvePolicy(TransactedDefinition.java:171) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.PolicyDefinition.resolvePolicy(PolicyDefinition.java:158) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.PolicyDefinition.createProcessor(PolicyDefinition.java:134) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069) ~[camel-core-2.16.2.jar:2.16.2]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Thanks,

The route which I have is as below,

```
<route id="createEmpFlow ">

    <from uri="direct:createEmpFlow "/>

        <policy ref="roleEmpUser">


        </policy>
</route>
```

I have wrapped it using the policy camel tag referring the roleUserEmp.

Comment: `SpringSecurityAccessPolicy` is not a route policy. please show the route you are using.

Comment: is there a java DSL example for the above? of setting up the policy within a route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SpringSecurityAccessPolicy` is not a `Policy`. You should use `SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy`, and configure it with your `accessDecisionManager`, `authenticationManager` and `SpringSecurityAccessPolicy`.

```
@Bean(name="policy")
public SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy springPolicy(AuthenticationManager authMgr, AccessDecisionManager accessMgr) {
    SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy policy = new SpringSecurityAuthorizationPolicy();

    // .. configure
    policy.setAuthenticationManager(authMgr);
    policy.setAccessDecisionManager(accessMgr);
    policy. setSpringSecurityAccessPolicy(new SpringSecurityAccessPolicy("ROLE_USER_EMP"));
    return policy;
}
```